# Run jupyterlab from wsl ubuntu with a windows shortcut

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jupyter-lab

i try to create a desktop shortcut in windows. I do this in link file:

```
wsl -u dio python3 -m jupyter lab --LabApp.token=''
```

But give this error(inside wsl work):

```
Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-lab` not found.
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. For some reason wsl in cmd dont see PATH. Then need link bin with all path on command line.

solution :

```
C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe ~/.local/bin/jupyter lab --LabApp.token='' --no-browser | wslview http://localhost:8888/lab && wsl --shutdown && exit
```